# ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments doesn't remove existing comments

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

### Description

Hey there,

I'm trying to build something that would add comments on top of a function.
Unfortunately, it seems like `ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments` does not allow me to replace existing comments.

I have tried:

- `ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments(node, [])`
- `ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments(node, undefined)`
- `node = ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments(node, [])`

But none of these works. Ultimately, my goal was to be able to replace existing comments that I would have generated by the new ones.

Any idea ? Thanks

### Reproduction

```
const transformFactory = (context: ts.TransformationContext) => (
  rootNode: ts.SourceFile
): ts.SourceFile => {
  const visit = (node: ts.Node) => {
    node = ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);

    ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments(node, []);

    return node;
  };

  return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
};

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
  path,
  source,
  ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
  true,
  ts.ScriptKind.TS
);
const result = ts.transform(sourceFile, [transformFactory]);
const resultPrinter = ts.createPrinter({ removeComments: false });

console.log(resultPrinter.printFile(result.transformed[0]));
```

Try the following transformer, and see how no comments are removed at all

Using `ts.createPrinter(..., { substituteNode(hint, node) { ... } })` doesn't help either

### Side note

It seems like `ts.getSyntheticLeadingComments()` doesn't work the way I expect it to either. It always returns `undefined`, which lead me to use the following utils although I'm not sure to entirely understand the purpose of it (borrowed from https://github.com/angular/tsickle/blob/6f5835a644f3c628a61e3dcd558bb9c59c73dc2f/src/transformer_util.ts#L257-L266)

```
/**
 * A replacement for ts.getLeadingCommentRanges that returns the union of synthetic and
 * non-synthetic comments on the given node, with their text included. The returned comments must
 * not be mutated, as their content might or might not be reflected back into the AST.
 */
export function getAllLeadingComments(node: ts.Node):
    ReadonlyArray<Readonly<ts.CommentRange&{text: string}>> {
  const allRanges: Array<Readonly<ts.CommentRange&{text: string}>> = [];
  const nodeText = node.getFullText();
  const cr = ts.getLeadingCommentRanges(nodeText, 0);
  if (cr) allRanges.push(...cr.map(c => ({...c, text: nodeText.substring(c.pos, c.end)})));
  const synthetic = ts.getSyntheticLeadingComments(node);
  if (synthetic) allRanges.push(...synthetic);
  return allRanges;
}
```

Comment: There is a GitHub issue on this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30191

Comment: Now that I look better it the same content :D

Comment: Are you trying to add jsdocs? Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17146 -- Btw, they're stored in the ast, but regular comments aren't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you expect the `*SyntheticLeadingComments` functions to impact source comments. They will not. They will only impact comments that were previously synthetized (ie added by you in code).

Actual comments are not kept as nodes in the AST. You can get actual source comments  using `getLeadingCommentRanges` and `getTrailingCommentRanges`.

A node has a `start` and an `end` position that do not include any comments. There is also a fullStart to the node which is the position including any leading comments. When a node is outputted this is how typescript knows how to copy the comments to the output.

If we use `setTextRange` to set the range of a node to exclude these existing comments the result is we are effectively removing them from the output and we can add out new comments using `setSyntheticLeadingComments`:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'

const transformFactory = (context: ts.TransformationContext) => (
    rootNode: ts.SourceFile
): ts.SourceFile => {
    const visit = (node: ts.Node) => {
        node = ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, context);
            if(ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node)) {
            let sourceFileText = node.getSourceFile().text;
            const existingComments = ts.getLeadingCommentRanges(sourceFileText, node.pos);
            if (existingComments) {
                // Log existing comments just for fun 
                for (const comment of existingComments) {
                    console.log(sourceFileText.substring(comment.pos, comment.end))
                }
                // Comment also attaches to the first child, we must remove it recursively.
                let removeComments =  (c: ts.Node) => {
                    if (c.getFullStart() === node.getFullStart()) {
                        ts.setTextRange(c, { pos: c.getStart(), end: c.getEnd() });
                    }
                    c = ts.visitEachChild(c, removeComments, context);
                    return c;
                }
                ts.visitEachChild(node, removeComments, context);
                ts.setTextRange(node, { pos: node.getStart(), end: node.getEnd() })
                ts.setSyntheticLeadingComments(node, [{
                    pos: -1,
                    end: -1,
                    hasTrailingNewLine: false,
                    text: "Improved comment",
                    kind: ts.SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia
                }]);

            }
        }
        return node;
    };

    return ts.visitNode(rootNode, visit);
};

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    "path.ts",
    `
// Original comment
function test () {

}
`,
    ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
    true,
    ts.ScriptKind.TS
);
const result = ts.transform(sourceFile, [transformFactory]);
const resultPrinter = ts.createPrinter({ removeComments: false });

console.log("!");
console.log(resultPrinter.printFile(result.transformed[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have been a bit imprecise, which makes your code not working for what I'm trying to do.

I'm not trying to add comments of top of `FunctionDeclaration`, but on top of `VariableStatement`. And for some reasons, `ts.setTextRange` doesn't seem to do the same effect as for `FunctionDeclaration`. It doesn't remove the existing comment, although the `node.start` and `node.end` doesn't include the comment. Sorry for the wrong initial topic, I thought I'd use functions to make it more simple to understand. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @FlavianDesverne it should .. I can't check right now but I will a bit later and get back to you. Could you provide some sample code you want to change ? What is in the file what the expected output would be ? That would help

Comment: Here's the output I get for the following code:

```
import { objectType } from "nexus";
//Improved comment
// Original comment
export const Toto = objectType({
    name: "Query",
    definition(t) {
        t.string("hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: Update: Code blocks doesn't work in comments. Here's a pastebin with the input, expected output, actual output, and my implementation (which simply replaces ts.isFunctionDeclaration with ts.isVariableStatement): https://pastebin.com/axhmk8eP. Thanks a ton for your help 

Comment: @FlavianDesverne apparently the comment attaches itself to the first child as well, we need to remove it recursively, I will update shortly the code

Comment: @FlavianDesverne did you get a chance to look at the code ? it should work now.